# If $f :R \to S$ is an isomorphism from ring $R$ to ring $S$, both with identity, does $f(1_R) = 1_S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

My attempted proof:

Let $a \in R$, then $f(a) = f(a \cdot 1_R)$ = $f(a) \cdot f(1_R)$, and for $f(a) \ne 0$, it gets canceled, so $1_S = f(1_R)$

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it gets canceled'? Note that $S$ is a ring.

Comment: Setting $a=1_R$ only shows that $f(1_R)$ is an idempotent...

Comment: I think "it gets cancelled" was intended to mean "acts like the identity."  So the OP succeeds in showing that $f(1)$ acts like the identity on $f(R)$, and as long as the OP realizes $f(R)=S$ that would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have cancelation in arbitrary rings. You have to show that $f(1_R)s=s$ for all $s \in S$. Hint: Use the fact that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R,S$ be rings and $f$ the isomorphism. To prove $f(1_R)=1_S$, we need to prove that for each $s\in S$, $f(1_R)s=s$. Therefore from uniqueness of $1_S$, we get $1_S=f(1_R)$.

Let $s\in S$. $f$ is an isomorphism therefore there exists $r\in R$ s.t $f(r)=s$.
So:
$$f(1_R)s=f(1_R)f(r)=f(1_Rr)=f(r)=s$$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have $f(r)=f(1_R)f(r)$. Since $f$ is surjective, we may choose $r$ so that $f(r)=1_S$. The result follows.